# How do I use an IF THEN function in Power BI over multiple queries?

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax, visualization

I am trying to filter an average amount (wage) from one query through a column (gender; 0 = male, 1 = female) belonging to different query.

So, I want put the different averages (query 1) for both genders (query 2) into one card or bar chart visualization.

Can I do this using DAX? Or do I need to merge the queries somehow?

Thank you!

Comment: No sure which "query" tag you wanted, but pretty sure it wasn't [tag:jquery]

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Table examples with some raw data and the outcome what you want is the minimum to be able to help you. And Yes, it is possible in DAX as well as in mquery but most likely not with the if statement..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean Tables vs Queries.  If you have a relationship between the table with the Gender and a table with the averages, then you just need to include the gender column and the average column in your results.